# How to access Data attribute in Button Click Event in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

How can I access a data attribute associated with a button from the onClick event handler of the button? Please see the code snippet below.

```js
function ComponentWithAttribute () {
    
function OnClicked() {

    alert("Value of data-val here"); 
  }
    return (
        <button
          onClick={OnClicked}
          data-value={'foo'}
         >
            Click Me!
         </button>
    )
}
export default ComponentWithAttribute;
```

Comment: This is clearly an antipattern. Place any data you need with your callback in the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `event` argument which is passed to any event handler:

```
function OnClicked(event) {
alert("Value of data-val here " + event.target.getAttribute("data-value"));   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function to accept event and access using dataset.

```
function onClicked(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use data attribute in button tag, instead directly pass that value to function parameter, This can be a dynamic value if you need it

```
function ComponentWithAttribute () {
                    
  function OnClicked(data) {
    console.log("Value of data-val here", data); 
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={() => OnClicked('foo')}>
     Click Me!
    </button>
  )
                }
export default ComponentWithAttribute;
```